# How to sort vertices of a polygon in counter clockwise order?

Tags: geometry, vectors, polygons

## How to sort vertices of a polygon in counter clockwise order?

I want to create a function (algorithm) which compares two vectors $\vec v$ and $\vec u$ which are vertices in a polygon. It should choose the vertex which counter clockwise index inside the polygon is higher. The first index should be the bottom left vertex.

[image: pentagon example]

I this example it should choose $\vec u$.

For the first quadrant I can say that $\vec u > \vec v$ if $|\vec u| > |\vec v|$ and $\forall\vec u > \forall\vec v$. The length should be weighted more than the angle in order that vertex 1 gets a lower index than vertex 2. But this rule only works for the first quadrant. I could first move the whole polygon into the first quadrant but I want to find a better solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for an analytical function or an algorithm? For the second case you could just loop over the vertices numbers.

Comment: Counter clockwise index from _where_?  Are you assuming that your polygons are convex?

Comment: Otherwise you can check the sign of the angles (u,v) but it depends on the center and could be complicated if the polygon is complex.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your polygon is convex, take any point in the interior of the polygon, e.g. the average of all the vertices. Then you can compute the angle of each vertex to the center point, and sort according to the computed angles. This will work for any point inside the polygon. Note you will get a circular ordering.

Comment: Some background from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_orientation#Orientation_of_a_simple_polygon).

Comment: This algorithm breaks when the polygon is a quadrilateral since all angles are equal. My solution was to take the midpoint and then move it very slightly by a value that will not move it outside of the polygon. After that, not all angles are perfectly equal, and the algorithm functions as normal

Answer (score 7):

Here is my Java code based on the correct answer: 1) get centroid coordinates 2) calculate degree between two point, sort the point based on the degree

```
 private static class Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "x=" + x + " y=" + y;
    }
}

public Point findCentroid(List<Point> points) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (Point p : points) {
        x += p.x;
        y += p.y;
    }
    Point center = new Point(0, 0);
    center.x = x / points.size();
    center.y = y / points.size();
    return center;
}

public List<Point> sortVerticies(List<Point> points) {
    // get centroid
    Point center = findCentroid(points);
    Collections.sort(points, (a, b) -> {
        double a1 = (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(a.x - center.x, a.y - center.y)) + 360) % 360;
        double a2 = (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(b.x - center.x, b.y - center.y)) + 360) % 360;
        return (int) (a1 - a2);
    });
    return points;
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the function `sortVerticices` will sort the points clockwise. To have them sorted counterclockwise replace `return (int) (a1 - a2);` with `return (int) (a2 - a1);`

Answer (score 0):

A faster alternative to the [previous java answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2722375/1000377) doesn't require any trig functions and works with an array where every even index has an x coordinate and every odd one has a y coordinate.

```
float[] elements = ...;
Arrays.quickSort(0, elements.length / 2, (k1, k2) -> {
    int a = k1 * 2, b = k2 * 2;
    float ax = elements[a], ay = elements[a+1], bx = elements[b], by = elements[b+1];
    float aa = ax / ay, ab = bx / by;
    return ((int)Math.signum(ay * by)) * Float.compare(aa, ab);
}, (a, b) -> {
    int ai = a * 2, bi = b * 2;
    float bx = elements[bi], by = elements[bi+1];
    elements[bi] = elements[ai];
    elements[bi+1] = elements[ai+1];
    elements[ai] = bx;
    elements[ai+1] = by;
});
```