# "How to sort vertices of a polygon in counter clockwise order?": Computing Angle?

Tags: geometry, vectors, polygons

my question relates to the answer to the following question:
[How to sort vertices of a polygon in counter clockwise order?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978642/how-to-sort-vertices-of-a-polygon-in-counter-clockwise-order)

I don't have a strong background in linear algebra... I don't understand this statement:

```
Then you can compute the angle of each vertex to the center point, and sort according to the computed angle
```

Is this a polar angle? What function could I use in R to compute this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\operatorname{atan2}$ is [defined](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Trig.html) [in R](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/atan2.php) so just use it. This is indeed a polar angle, with a few subtleties.

Choose a "central point" $(\hat x, \hat y)$, and for each point $(x,y)$ calculate its angle as $\operatorname{atan2}(x-\hat x,y-\hat y)$. Sort the points using those angles as keys, and there is your polygon.

Note that if the polygon is not convex you may get a different answer if you choose a different "central point". Also make sure the point really is "inside" the polygon. Choosing the average values of $x$ and of $y$ should work well enough.